# Group by every Nth Value and Pivot the data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the data in the below format as shown in the below image and around 50 million records. Please help me to get the desired output with performance.

I need to look for D records (highlighted in red) and pivot the data to align with above H record (highlighted in yellow).

For example in the below screenshot, I have first row H and second row D so I need D row should be aligned with above h row as shown in desired output.

3rd row - H and 4,5,6,7th rows -D .These 4,5,6, 7th row data needs to align with 3rd row H record.

[image]

Comment: This is not going to be a feature that SSIS can deliver

Comment: Well, a script transformation can do it, but it will loop row-by-row, and performance may not be great.   Probably as good as any other solution though.

Comment: The challenge with this @TabAlleman, at least in my mind, is that the data flow isn't going to accept arbitrarily long columns. At design time, they'd need to make an estimate of how many columns they'll need (N + MaxDepthOfDRows * 3) for the output buffer and when they hit max depth+1 this breaks. $.02

Comment: Well the script component could loop through the rows twice, once just to find the longest pivoted row (which determines number of output columns needed), and then again to actually do the pivot.   But now that I think about it, the number of columns might have to be determined in a script task prior to the dataflow.   I can't remember if a script transformation can wait until it receives all rows before processing, or does it only process one row at a time?